# Conflict between javascript codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm creating a web application in which the main page is a timeline, and this timeline should update its content automatically. I am using the setTimeOut function of JQuery to update the timeline every x seconds.

But I also have another JavaScript code to show hidden elements of that item when clicking on the div.

The two code work perfectly when alone, except when I try to use both on the page. **The error is as follows** After the timeline is updated by setTimeOut, the second code (clicking on the div to show / hide elements) no longer works. I tried to solve it in several ways and I could not and also I did not find solutions. Does anyone know what can it be? ***I also accept tips on how to upgrade my timeline, such as updating only when there are new item entries, instead of every x seconds.***

```js
setTimeout("my_function();", 9000);
    function my_function() {
      $('#timeline').load(location.href + ' #timeline')
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
      var itemsDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.timeline-item');
      itemsDivs.forEach(function (itemsDiv) {

        itemsDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
          var itemId = this.getAttribute('item-id')
          var display = document.getElementById('comment-form-' + itemId).style.display
          if (display == 'none')
            document.getElementById('comment-form-' + itemId).style.display = 'block'
          else
            document.getElementById('comment-form-' + itemId).style.display = 'none'
        })
      })
    })
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row example-basic">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
          {% for item in items %}
          <li item-id={{item.id}} class="timeline-item">
            <div class="timeline-info">
              <span>{{item.data.strftime('%c')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-marker"></div>
            <div class="timeline-content">
              <h3 class="timeline-title">{{item.analista}} recomenda {{item.ativo}} a R${{item.preco}}.</h3>
              <p>Fonte:{{item.fonte}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="comment-form-{{ item.id }}" style="display: none;">
              {{item.coments}} <br><span id='dataalvo'>Data Alvo: {{item.dataalvo}}</span>
            </div>
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
          <li class="timeline-item period">
            <div class="timeline-info"></div>
            <div class="timeline-marker"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are binding click eventlistener on every element pretty much manually that is why when the items reload the listeners are gone with them. Quickest solution would be to move your code (adding listener) to a function and call it again every time you reload items. Of course there are better and more sophisticated answers but mine is just the quickest fix to given problem without rewriting a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must re-register your event listeners.

Event listeners in Javascript do not attach to a selector, but to the actual elements themselves. `document.querySelectorAll('.timeline-item')` selects all DOM elements that currently have the `.timeline-item` selector. After 9 seconds (per your `setTimeout` function), you delete all your `.timeline-item`s and get new up-to-date ones ([`load()` deletes all inner HTML and replaces it with the new HTML](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

If you wish for these newly added `.timeline-item`s to have event listeners, then you need to add them. Something like this might work for you:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Register event listeners again after the load is complete
  $('#timeline').load(location.href + ' #timeline', function() {
    registerEventListeners();
  });
}, 9000);

// Register event listeners once the document is finished loading
$(document).ready(function () {
  registerEventListeners();
});

/**
 * Registers event listeners to all `.timeline-item` elements.
 */
function registerEventListeners() {
  var itemsDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.timeline-item');
  itemsDivs.forEach(function (itemsDiv) {

    itemsDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var itemId = this.getAttribute('item-id')
      var display = document.getElementById('comment-form-' + itemId).style.display
      if (display == 'none')
        document.getElementById('comment-form-' + itemId).style.display = 'block'
      else
        document.getElementById('comment-form-' + itemId).style.display = 'none'
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: this way it worked, but it seems that the settimeout only runs once

Comment: @PedroLyra `setTimeout` is designed to only run once. If you want your code to repeat then use `setInterval` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the reason is that： your div event is attached in document.ready , after x seconds over,  my_function is executed , the original item divs is removed from the page , and the new item divs  has not been attached event .
**so, bind the div event in  $('#timeline').loaded  event.**